# Building SDL2 for android (on OSX 10.11.6) w/ ndk-build fatally errors on different SDL files every time

Tags: android, c++, macos, android-ndk, sdl-2

I have a basic SDL2 compiling for android setup.

When I run `ndk-build`, it spits out a bit error log (below in its entirety), with the key line (i believe) being this:

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_dummyaudio.c
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x7fb5830ed1c0: i32 = ARMISD::SSAT 0x7fb5830d9080, Constant:i32<15>
```

Each time I compile (literally just re-type `ndk-build`), it errors at a different spot. For example:

```
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_clipboardevents.c
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x7fbf7187dfc0: i32 = ARMISD::SSAT 0x7fbf72152880, Constant:i32<15>
```

And I can just keep typing `nkd-build` and it keeps hopping around, erroring in different places (I've tried just doing it like 50 times in a row to see what would happen, and it doesn't seem to ever stabilize or resolve itself).

I've restarted the computer, done `ndk-build clean`, everything I can think of.

Here's the output from the first example. All other outputs look very similar.

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-23 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 10 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
make[1]: Entering directory `/Users/phildo/Desktop/doodle_plus/android-project'
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[armeabi-v7a] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[x86] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_assert.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_error.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_hints.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_log.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audio.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audiocvt.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audiodev.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_audiotypecvt.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_mixer.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_wave.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_androidaudio.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : SDL2 <= SDL_dummyaudio.c
fatal error: error in backend: Cannot select: 0x7fb5830ed1c0: i32 = ARMISD::SSAT 0x7fb5830d9080, Constant:i32<15>
  0x7fb5830d9080: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d9240, 0x7fb5830ed000
    0x7fb5830d9240: i32 = sra 0x7fb5830ed3f0, Constant:i32<8>
      0x7fb5830ed3f0: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d8600, 0x7fb5830d8a60
        0x7fb5830d8600: i32 = add 0x7fb5830dc110, 0x7fb5830ed8c0
          0x7fb5830dc110: i32 = mul 0x7fb5830d9320, 0x7fb5830dc500
            0x7fb5830d9320: i32,ch = load<LD2[%15](tbaa=<0x7fb5824276a8>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830d94e0, undef:i32
              0x7fb5830d94e0: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d91d0, Constant:i32<2>
                0x7fb5830d91d0: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg2
                  0x7fb5830dc960: i32 = Register %vreg2
                0x7fb5830d8670: i32 = Constant<2>
              0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
            0x7fb5830dc500: i32,ch = load<LD2[%12](tbaa=<0x7fb582445738>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830d8f30, undef:i32
              0x7fb5830d8f30: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d8d70, Constant:i32<6>
                0x7fb5830d8d70: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg0
                  0x7fb5830ed690: i32 = Register %vreg0
                0x7fb5830dcab0: i32 = Constant<6>
              0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
          0x7fb5830ed8c0: i32 = mul 0x7fb5830d90f0, 0x7fb5830dc810
            0x7fb5830d90f0: i32,ch = load<LD2[%2](tbaa=<0x7fb5824276a8>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830d91d0, undef:i32
              0x7fb5830d91d0: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg2
                0x7fb5830dc960: i32 = Register %vreg2
              0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
            0x7fb5830dc810: i32,ch = load<LD2[%6](tbaa=<0x7fb582445738>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830dc420, undef:i32
              0x7fb5830dc420: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d8d70, Constant:i32<4>
                0x7fb5830d8d70: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg0
                  0x7fb5830ed690: i32 = Register %vreg0
                0x7fb5830dbfc0: i32 = Constant<4>
              0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
        0x7fb5830d8a60: i32 = srl 0x7fb5830d8c20, Constant:i32<24>
          0x7fb5830d8c20: i32 = sra 0x7fb5830d8600, Constant:i32<31>
            0x7fb5830d8600: i32 = add 0x7fb5830dc110, 0x7fb5830ed8c0
              0x7fb5830dc110: i32 = mul 0x7fb5830d9320, 0x7fb5830dc500
                0x7fb5830d9320: i32,ch = load<LD2[%15](tbaa=<0x7fb5824276a8>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830d94e0, undef:i32
                  0x7fb5830d94e0: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d91d0, Constant:i32<2>


                  0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
                0x7fb5830dc500: i32,ch = load<LD2[%12](tbaa=<0x7fb582445738>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830d8f30, undef:i32
                  0x7fb5830d8f30: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d8d70, Constant:i32<6>


                  0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
              0x7fb5830ed8c0: i32 = mul 0x7fb5830d90f0, 0x7fb5830dc810
                0x7fb5830d90f0: i32,ch = load<LD2[%2](tbaa=<0x7fb5824276a8>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830d91d0, undef:i32
                  0x7fb5830d91d0: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg2

                  0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
                0x7fb5830dc810: i32,ch = load<LD2[%6](tbaa=<0x7fb582445738>), sext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830dc420, undef:i32
                  0x7fb5830dc420: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d8d70, Constant:i32<4>


                  0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
            0x7fb5830ed070: i32 = Constant<31>
          0x7fb5830dc8f0: i32 = Constant<24>
      0x7fb5830d9010: i32 = Constant<8>
    0x7fb5830ed000: i32 = mul 0x7fb5830d8b40, 0x7fb5830ed700
      0x7fb5830d8b40: i32,ch = load<LD2[%24](tbaa=<0x7fb582445738>), zext from i16> 0x7fb582724e90, 0x7fb5830ed5b0, undef:i32
        0x7fb5830ed5b0: i32 = add 0x7fb5830d8d70, Constant:i32<2>
          0x7fb5830d8d70: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg0
            0x7fb5830ed690: i32 = Register %vreg0
          0x7fb5830d8670: i32 = Constant<2>
        0x7fb5830d8bb0: i32 = undef
      0x7fb5830ed700: i32 = ARMISD::CMOV 0x7fb5830dc730, 0x7fb5830dcce0, Constant:i32<0>, Register:i32 %CPSR, 0x7fb5830d8750
        0x7fb5830dc730: i32 = add 0x7fb5830dcce0, Constant:i32<-16>
          0x7fb5830dcce0: i32 = AssertZext 0x7fb5830dca40, ValueType:ch:i8
            0x7fb5830dca40: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg1
              0x7fb5830d8de0: i32 = Register %vreg1
          0x7fb5830d8910: i32 = Constant<-16>
        0x7fb5830dcce0: i32 = AssertZext 0x7fb5830dca40, ValueType:ch:i8
          0x7fb5830dca40: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg1
            0x7fb5830d8de0: i32 = Register %vreg1
        0x7fb5830ed540: i32 = Constant<0>
        0x7fb5830d88a0: i32 = Register %CPSR
        0x7fb5830d8750: glue = ARMISD::CMPZ 0x7fb5830dc650, Constant:i32<0>
          0x7fb5830dc650: i32 = and 0x7fb5830dcce0, Constant:i32<8>
            0x7fb5830dcce0: i32 = AssertZext 0x7fb5830dca40, ValueType:ch:i8
              0x7fb5830dca40: i32,ch = CopyFromReg 0x7fb582724e90, Register:i32 %vreg1
                0x7fb5830d8de0: i32 = Register %vreg1
            0x7fb5830d9010: i32 = Constant<8>
          0x7fb5830ed540: i32 = Constant<0>
  0x7fb5830dc2d0: i32 = Constant<15>
In function: MS_ADPCM_nibble
clang: error: clang frontend command failed with exit code 70 (use -v to see invocation)
Android clang version 3.8.275480  (based on LLVM 3.8.275480)
Target: armv5te-none-linux-android
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r14/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 
********************

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/g6/j2xtb5gn5vg_0cx52d35t1ww0000gn/T/SDL_wave-aa9d26.c
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/g6/j2xtb5gn5vg_0cx52d35t1ww0000gn/T/SDL_wave-aa9d26.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg: 

********************
make[1]: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2/src/audio/SDL_wave.o] Error 70
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Turns out it's a bug in LLVM? The way to fix it until it's resolved is to put `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9` in `jni/Application.mk` to switch to gcc until it's fixed.